# Create DataTemplate Binding in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

**Solution**

I found this [post](https://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/DataTemplateCreation/) which helped me to bind the data template.  I needed to add the data template to the `Applicaiton.Current.Resources` with a key like so (in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add the data template to the Application.Current.Resources
    var _dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.TryFindResource("ProjectSpecificTemplate");
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(_dataTemplate.DataTemplateKey, _dataTemplate);

    // Add the view models to TabsViewModel.Tabs
    TabsViewModel _tabs = (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).TabsViewModel;
    _tabs.Tabs.Insert(0, (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).ProjectSpecificViewModel);

    // Set selected tab
    _tabs.SelectedTabViewModel = _tabs.Tabs[1];

}
```

Once I added this, the view model could associate itself with the correct view.

**OP**

When specifying a tab control I typically use the following user control to define the various data templates and their binding's:

**TabsUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DelphiaLibrary.Views.TabsUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DelphiaLibrary.ViewModels"
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:DelphiaLibrary.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 

             DataContext="{Binding TabsViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionary/StylesDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabViewModel}">

        <TabControl.Resources>

            <!-- Project Specific tab -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProjectSpecificViewModel}">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <v:ProjectSpecificUserControl />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>

            <!-- System Setup tab -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SystemSetupViewModel}">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <v:SystemSetupUserControl />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TabControl.Resources>

    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

**TabsViewModel.cs**

```
public class TabsViewModel : ViewModelBase<TabsViewModel>
{
    #region Initialization and Cleanup

    // Default ctor
    /// <summary>
    /// Default TabsViewModel constructor
    /// </summary>
    public TabsViewModel()
    {
        (Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).TabsViewModel = this;
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>();

        LoadTabInfo();
        SelectedTabViewModel = Tabs.First();
    }

    #endregion Initialization and Cleanup


    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of tab objects
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs 
    {
        get { return _Tabs; }
        set
        {
            if (this._Tabs != value)
            {
                this._Tabs = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Tabs);
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> _Tabs;

    /// <summary>
    /// SelectedTabViewModel property which also calls the TabSelected()
    /// method when the SelectedTab has changed
    /// </summary>
    public ITabViewModel SelectedTabViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedTabViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
           if (this._SelectedTabViewModel != value && value != null)
           {
               this._SelectedTabViewModel = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedTabViewModel);
           }
        }
    }
    private ITabViewModel _SelectedTabViewModel;

. . .
```

This `TabsUserControl` is added to the `MainWindow.xaml` file and controls what tab to display based on user selection.  `TabsUserControl` also defines what view is associated with a particular view model.

In the example above I have a ViewModel called `TabsViewModel` which has the properties `Tabs` (ObservableCollection) and `SelectedTabsViewModel` (ITabViewModel).  Whenever the `SelectedTabsViewModel` changes, the corresponding tab user control is selected and displayed.  If `ProjectSpecificViewModel` was chosen, then the `ProjectSpecificUserControl` would be shown in the `TabControl`.

Because we use this same setup on a number of different projects, with a number of stock tabs (System Setup, About, etc.) I have moved all of this code into a library DLL file.  However, in moving everything to the DLL, I can no longer add a new tab and view model to the `TabsUserControl` resources.

I now have a new project using this library DLL and I am trying to add a project specific tab (one that doesn't belong in the DLL) to `TabsUserControl`.

**ProjectSpecificUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BaseApp.Views.ProjectSpecificUserControl"

                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

                 DataContext="{Binding ProjectSpecificViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Success" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

I have successfully added this project specific tab view model to the collection of Tabs in the code behind of `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabsViewModel _tabs = (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).TabsViewModel;
        _tabs.Tabs.Insert(0, (App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).ProjectSpecificViewModel);    

        _tabs.SelectedTabViewModel = _tabs.Tabs[0];

    }
. . .
}
```

I also added the `DataTemplate` to `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="BaseApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:BaseApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BaseApp.ViewModels"
        xmlns:v_dc="clr-namespace:DelphiaLibrary.Views;assembly=DelphiaLibrary"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- ProjectSpecific tab -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ProjectSpecificTemplate"
                      DataType="{x:Type vm:ProjectSpecificViewModel}">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MainContentHeight}">
                <v:ProjectSpecificUserControl />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
. . .
```

But cannot find a way to associate the view with the view model.

[image]

Comment: Yes, put the template in the Resources, give it an `x:Key` attribute, code behind can pass that key value to `FindResource()`. You'd ordinarily write a `DataTemplateSelector` that does that, and give that `DataTemplateSelector` to the tab control as a `ContentTemplateSelector` or whatever. But you're talking about "binding", so maybe you want something else. Can you show me the binding you have now?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Could you elaborate on this process?  Do I put the template in the Window.Resources (in this case a Window)?

Comment: That would be a safe place in terms of being able to get to it.

Comment: Are you asking on how to create the actual DataTemplate programmatically?

Comment: @mm8 I have the data template defined in a UserControl (XAML file).  I just need to add this data template and binding to my code, but in the code-behind, not in the XAML.

Comment: Where do you need to add it to? And what binding are you referring to?

Comment: @mm8 I think when he says "binding" he means "assignment".

Comment: @BrianKE You're being far too secretive here. Show us enough of the UserControl to understand what you're trying to do. If you want directions from your house to the airport, you can't just give us a map of the terminal and the runways. We need to know where your house is *relative to* the airport, do you see? There's no general answer for "which streets do you take to get from any given house to any given airport".

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thank you for taking your time on this.  I was hoping what I had included in the first post would be sufficient.  I have update the port to include the code for all the files that I think would be involved in this issue.